# Что использует IIS в качестве TLS транспорта?

Tags: .net, windows, iis, iis-7, iis-10

Согласно этой статье в блоге: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/perfdude/2008/12/30/lsass-exe-and-w3wp-exe-analyzing-ssl-performance-in-iis-6-0/ начиная с IIS 7.0 не использует LSASS для TLS.

Что же используется в IIS 7.0+ в качестве TLS транспорта?

Answer (score 0):

Если IIS6 был монолитным сервером, то IIS7 имеет модульную структуру.

Приём HTTP и HTTPS в IIS6 шёл в пользовательском режиме операционной системы ОС Windows, а в IIS7 это делается в режиме ядра (драйвером HTTP.SYS).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылки по теме:

- [habrahabr - Основы архитектуры IIS](https://habrahabr.ru/post/189086/)
- [НОУ ИНТУИТ: Обзор архитектуры IIS 7.0](https://youtu.be/4_aeh0QeoNI?t=1214)