# C# сервер,запросы,потоки, как создается очередь запросов?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, сервер, запрос, веб-сервер

Я новичок во всём, что связано с запросами и потоками. В сети нашел вот такой пример сервера, который для каждого запроса создает поток и потом в отдельном потоке обрабатывает этот запрос(если я правильно понял). Вопрос такой, что происходит, когда на сервер отправляется большое количество запросов? Все запросы добавляются в какую-то очередь и потом поочередно выгружаются?

Если есть какая-то очередь, то можно ли вмешаться в эту очередь и "отклонить" запросы?

```
namespace TestServer
{
    internal class AsyncHttpServer : IDisposable
    {
        public AsyncHttpServer()
        {
            listener = new HttpListener();
        }

        public void Start(string prefix)
        {
            lock (listener)
            {
                if (!isRunning)
                {
                    listener.Prefixes.Clear();
                    listener.Prefixes.Add(prefix);
                    listener.Start();

                    listenerThread = new Thread(Listen)
                    {
                        IsBackground = true,
                        Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest
                    };
                    listenerThread.Start();
                    isRunning = true;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            lock (listener)
            {
                if (!isRunning)
                    return;
                listener.Stop();
                listenerThread.Abort();
                listenerThread.Join();

                isRunning = false;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (disposed)
                return;
            disposed = true;
            Stop();
            listener.Close();
        }

        private void Listen()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (listener.IsListening)
                    {
                        var context = listener.GetContext();
                        Task.Run(() => HandleContextAsync(context));
                    }
                    else Thread.Sleep(0);
                }
                catch (ThreadAbortException)
                {
                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    Console.Write(error);
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task HandleContextAsync(HttpListenerContext listenerContext)
        {
            listenerContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(listenerContext.Response.OutputStream))
                writer.WriteLine("");
        }

        private readonly HttpListener listener;

        private Thread listenerThread;
        private bool disposed;
        private volatile bool isRunning;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Да Web-сервер имеет очередь.
Если кол-во запросов превышает кол-во доступных мест в очереди, то выкидывается ошибка доступа к ресурсу.

Повышать/понижать слоты в очереди можно в оснастке веб-сервера.

Отклонять запросы тоже можно. Web-сервер, как правило, имеет списки фильтрации.

Надеюсь, я правильно понял вопрос.

Comment: Да, вопрос понят правильно, а как можно взаимодействовать с этой очередью, где она находится?

Comment: @StriBog , что вы понимаете под взаимодействием? Изменять пороги? Я думаю, что wmi это может

Comment: Хочу отклонить запросы, до которых точно знаю, что очередь дойдет не скоро

Comment: Т.е. при большом количество запросов, начинать отклонять новые запросы, пока система не разгрузиться

Comment: Зависит от веб сервера. Если есть у него API, то вы это можете сделать. Так же на веб сервере можно настроить тайм-аут. Может быть вам этого будет достаточно?

Comment: `listener.TimeoutManager.RequestQueue = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);` это оно?

Answer (score 0):

В дополнении к сказанному почитайте вот эти топики:

1. [Что использует IIS в качестве TLS транспорта?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/776882/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b5%d1%82-iis-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5-tls-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15417062/changing-http-sys-kernel-queue-limit-when-using-net-httplistener